# How can I shift a string to right and insert spaces?

Tags: c, string

***No need for answers anymore***, Of course, you can still post a solution.

I'm trying to create a Farfallino Alphabet encoder, but i can't wonder how to shift the string to right and insert spaces, to allow to insert new chars into the string.

This is my code:

```
void farfallinoEncoder(char *str){
  int i,j, lenght=strlen(str);
  char fT[4];

  for(i=0; i<lenght;i++){

    switch(str[i]){
        case 'a':
            strcpy(fT,"afa");
            break;
        case 'A':
            strcpy(fT,"Afa");
            break;
        case 'e':
            strcpy(fT,"efe");
            break;
        case 'E':
            strcpy(fT,"Efe");
            break;
        case 'i':
            strcpy(fT,"ifi");
            break;
        case 'I':
            strcpy(fT,"Ifi");
            break;
        case 'o':
            strcpy(fT,"ofo");
            break;
        case 'O':
            strcpy(fT,"Ofo");
            break;
        case 'u':
            strcpy(fT,"ufu");
            break;
        case 'U':
            strcpy(fT,"Ufu");
            break;
        default:
            printf("\n\tNope!\n"); //This message is for debug purpose only
            continue;
    }

    printf("\n\tOk!\n"); //This message is for debug purpose only

    shiftRight(str, i);

    //I'm going to add the new chars here
    for (j=0;j<strlen(fT);j++) {
        str[i+j]=fT[j];
    }
    i+=3;

    lenght=strlen(str);
  }
}
```

I need to shift the string to right and insert spaces to be able to replace chars. 
This is my shiftRight function:

```
void shiftRight(char *str, int pos){
  int i;

  char temp=str[pos], temp1;
  for (i=pos;i<strlen(str); i++) {
      temp1 = str[i];
      str[i] = temp;
      temp = temp1;
  }
}
```

But it's not doing what i'd like to! I'd like to create room for new characters, but I can't wonder how. For now I'm simply overwriting the old ones.

For example, if the input is "Ciao", the output must be "Cifiafaofo", but instead the function gives me "Cifi" only.

I can't use dynamic memory allocation because they haven't been taught in mine class yet.

Comment: Post how `shiftRight` is called.  "example if the input is "Ciao", the output must be "Cifiafaofo" is insufficient.  Research [MCVE]

Comment: In general, code certainly does not assure  a _null character_ when lengthening a string.

Comment: The function shiftRight is called in function farfallinoEncoder. The problem is, I think, in shiftRigtht function, that doesn't create enough spaces.

Comment: @MattGeek given an input of some size (let's say - `n`) - do you know in advance what is the size of the output?  A possible solution might use `malloc`/`realloc`, allocating the needed space for the output

Comment: I can't wonder how to create room for new characters.

Comment: @MattGeek "I can't wonder how to create room for new characters" --> how did you create room for the old characters - that is still now shown.  The space needed for the new looks to be 3x the old.  So until a [MCVE] appears, the post remains vague.

Comment: @MattGeek "I can't use (this) or (that) " and other such requirements need to be post , else a good solution will later incur a new restriction - with no end in sight.

Comment: @chux Has now Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example?

Comment: `memmove(str + 3, str + 1, strlen(str) - 1)`. But it would be more efficient to start from the end.

Comment: @ensc why to use memmove?

Comment: because memory areas are overlapping (--> `memcpy()` not possible)

Comment: Ok, I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: @MattGeek obviously you're not allocating enough space for the midified string. In the example you gave, `str` is of length 4, where your wanted result is of length 10. As I mentioned earlier - you can allocate such space on demand using `malloc`. good luck

Comment: @ensc memmove is too complex for me and is not working.

Comment: easiest is to have one more array, go then through the first array letter by letter and either copy the letter or put replacement in new array. otherwise you would need that your original array is big enough to contain the expansions.

Comment: @AndersK. Yes, I will go with that, thanks! As usual, I make my life more complex than it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough to use 2 passes: once to find the new length and 2nd to do the moving.

Real code often requires array size checking to prevent buffer over-runs,

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *farfallino_haystack = "AEIOUaeiou";

size_t farfallino_encoder_size(const char *str) {
  size_t sz = 1; // \0
  while (*str) {
    int needle = *str;
    // look for a needle in a hay stack
    if (strchr(farfallino_haystack, needle)) {
      sz += 3;
    } else {
      sz += 1;
    }
    str++;
  }
  return sz;
}

int farfallino_encode_inplace(char *str, size_t sz) {
  size_t sz_needed = farfallino_encoder_size(str);
  if (sz_needed > sz) {
    return -1; // let calling code handle this
  }
  size_t len_needed = sz_needed - 1;
  size_t len_was = strlen(str);
  str[len_needed] = '\0';

  // Starting as the end and working to the "left"
  // while some encoding work still needed
  while (len_needed > len_was) {
    int needle = str[--len_was];
    if (strchr(farfallino_haystack, needle)) {
      str[--len_needed] = tolower(needle);
      str[--len_needed] = 'f';
      str[--len_needed] = needle;
    } else {
      str[--len_needed] = needle;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Test

```
void farfallino_encode_test(char *str, size_t sz) {
  size_t n = farfallino_encoder_size(str);
  printf("%zu <%s> --> ", sz, str);
  if (farfallino_encode_inplace(str, sz)) {
    puts("too small");
  } else {
    printf("%zu <%s>\n", n, str);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  char buf[11];
  strcpy(buf, "Ciao");
  farfallino_encode_test(buf, sizeof buf);
  strcpy(buf, "ABCDE");
  farfallino_encode_test(buf, sizeof buf);
  strcpy(buf, "abcdefghi");
  farfallino_encode_test(buf, sizeof buf);
}
```

Output

```
11 <Ciao> --> 11 <Cifiafaofo>
11 <ABCDE> --> 10 <AfaBCDEfe>
11 <abcdefghi> --> too small
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be be more efficient to start from the end of string because this will reduce the complexity from O(n^2) to O(n).  Assuming, `str` is large enough to hold the additional characters (e.g. declare it in the caller like `char  buf[128] = "Ciao";`), you can implement your encoder like:

```
void convert(char str[])
{
    typedef char        repl_t[3];
    static repl_t const MAP[] = {
        ['a'] = "afa",
        ['A'] = "Afa",
        ['e'] = "efe",
        ['E'] = "Efe",
        ['i'] = "ifi",
        ['I'] = "Ifi",
        ['o'] = "ofo",
        ['O'] = "Ofo",
        ['u'] = "ufu",
        ['U'] = "Ufu",
    };
    static size_t const     MAP_LEN = sizeof MAP / sizeof MAP[0];

    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *out = str + len * sizeof MAP[0];

    *out = '\0';
    while (len > 0) {
        size_t  c = str[len - 1];

        if (c >= MAP_LEN || MAP[c][0] == '\0') {
            out -= 1;
            *out = c;
        } else {
            out -= sizeof MAP[c];
            memcpy(out, MAP[c], sizeof MAP[c]);
        }

        --len;
    }

    memmove(str, out, strlen(out) + 1);
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer not to rewrite my code entirely, and this complex. I'm glad if you help me to get the code I've already written working. If you watch the entire source code(I linked), the string is already over-dimensioned.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this solution, thanks to @AndersK.

```
void farfallinoEncoder(char *str, char *translated){
  int i,l=0;

  for (i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){
      switch( tolower((unsigned char)str[i]) ){
          case 'a':
          case 'e':
          case 'i':
          case 'o':
          case 'u':
              translated[l]=str[i];

              if( isupper((unsigned char)str[i]) )
                  translated[l+1]='F';
              else
                  translated[l+1]='f';

              translated[l+2]=str[i];

              l+=3;
              break;
         default:
              translated[l]=str[i];
              l++;
              break;
      }
  }

  translated[l]='\0';
}
```

I should stop complicating my life uselessly, thanks all for your patience and collaboration. If you found any other solution, post it and I'll have a look at it! ;D